# Understanding hfeed

Tags: seo, microformats

Been looking around online to get a grasp of this. All the sources say that using the class of "hfeed" tells google that your content is syndicated or blog material. My theme has hfeed on all the custom post types and even the page templates that display them, but these are all static pages with content that will not change.

Is this something I will want to remove or is it serving a purpose here that I don't see? Is it hurting my site by telling google the content is syndicated?

When is the correct use case for this class? Any resources you feel I should read to understand this would be greatly appreciated. I am currently reading through http://microformats.org/wiki/hAtom and http://atomenabled.org/ but not really understanding the answer to my question yet.

Comment: The first thing you should learn about microformat is that it does not improve SEO. It ***may*** display extra data in the results and ***may*** improve click rates.

Comment: Do you ask about this Microformat in general, or about how Google makes use of this Microformat? If the latter, do you have any source that claims that Google would support it at all?

Comment: I am specifically asking about how Google will interpret this. And yes, the Google Search Console would be my source...on the structured data section, the site in question has errors related to "hentry" and "hatom". The source column for both of these reads "Markup: microformats.org". If Google did not support it, I would not expect them to reference errors related to it then.

Comment: @SimonHayter If it has no effect on SEO then why does google show related errors on the search console? I can think of many other things that can improve click through rates and such that Google does not help us with on the Search Console. Does Google not prefer content that is more semantically structured? (I'm not challenging your point, this is a legitimate question)

Comment: The search console, aka webmaster tools is for website indexing and aiding webmasters, it has little, if any to do with SEO apart from duplicate content warnings, speed reporting, metas and descriptions etc, even the links provided in Webmaster tools are samples, its not designed as a SEO tool. Just because you see a error in the console doesn't necessary mean your SEO is effected. Millions of sites rank without microdata, Google has yet to reward for it, other than displaying rich data. I wish I was wrong, but I'm not sadly.

Comment: I'm not saying not to have microdata, it does help Google understand the content, but to go far as to say it helps SEO, I'd be wrong other than improving CTR which can indirectly increase SEO leads. Use microdata to help for pages to display better in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Got a website where hAtom feed is implemented correctly - with author, update, published - and a website where I have removed all hentry classes.
I don't feel any difference, but seeing search console without errors brings me some satisfaction :D